# How to move custom popuwindow in android

Tags: android

I am displaying a custom poupwindow to the user. If the user drags the popup window, I want to move the position of the popup window.
Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: "Dialog doesn't have any Touch event listeners... " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948756/how-to-move-the-custom-dialog-box

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.y = -60;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
dialog.show();
```

This will displace your dialog 60 pixels to the left of the screen. Playing with lp variable inside of an onTouch listener applied to the draggable portion of the dialog will do the trick.