# How to move the custom dialog box?

Tags: android

I am beginner in android. I am creating a Custom Dialog box, it is working fine. But this dialog box does not moved. How to move this custom dialog box. For example in windows contains Notepad, Paint, etc. When you click this (Notepad, Paint, etc) title bar you can move the position. If it is possible please send information how to move dialog box. Otherwise if it is not possible send Reason. Please reply your answers and comments are valuable me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything before?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do something like put the finger on the title and move the dialog box but you should be able to use margin or padding if you don't want to center it.

Comment: I tried to only android:gravity.

Comment: I'm not sure. But, You should use some `SufaceView` Classes.

Comment: If you have lot of item to display in custom dialog box then use can use Activity with Theme:dialog

Comment: My dialog box appear in few seconds. It does not take lot of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dialog doesn't have any Touch event listeners so you might possibly create an Activity, implement onTouchListener on it, and in manifest file

`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">`

Now your Activity will look like a DialogBox, and you can implement the view's `setOnTouchListener()` and write the required code in that listener.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got a Re-sized window. I tried setOnTouchListener(). It's working fine. I need only moving part code. For example X,Y position is how to mentioned in the Touch-Listener.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very helping to me.